# PCIE 6/8pin clarification

Tags: gpu, pci-express, connector

I was getting a new GPU.

The GPU requires 2 6pin PCIE connectors.

However my PSU manuel (Seasonic S12II 620) says that the PSU has one 6pin and one 6/8pin.

Could I have some clarification on what the 6/8 pin connector is exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an 8-pin plug, and the housing around two of the pins detaches from the rest of the plug so it can also be plugged into a 6-pin connector.